# delete everything after keyword

Tags: powershell, ini, compareobject

I try to merge to files with `Compare-Object` and I got a file like this:

```
Number=5
Example=4
Track=1000
Date=07/08/2018 19:51:16
MatCaissierePDAAssoc=
NomImpPDAAssoc=
TpeForceLectPan=0
Number=1
Example=1
Track=0
Date=01/01/1999
```

You can see it repeats with Number=1. Except with a different value.
I would like to delete everything (everything means not only "= 1") after my keyword "Number" and my keyword itself.

This is what I did so far:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "D:\all"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $name = dir $file.FullName | select -ExpandProperty Name

    Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content D:\original\test.ini) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $file.FullName) -PassThru |
        Out-File ('D:\output\' + $name)
}
```

And I would like to delete all lines with "Track" and "Date".

My Result should look like this:

```
Number=5
Example=4
MatCaissierePDAAssoc=
NomImpPDAAssoc=
TpeForceLectPan=0
```

In fact I need something to delete double keys in my file.

Comment: Can you show what the expected result would before for the sample input you have provided.

Comment: sure, so everything, means every line, after a keyword should be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
# read existing file
$fileContent = Get-Content C:\tmp\so01.txt

# iterate over lines
foreach($line in $fileContent) {
  # filter lines beginning with 'Track' or 'Number'
  if((-not $line.StartsWith('Track')) -and (-not $line.StartsWith('Number'))) {
    # output lines to new file
    $line | Add-Content C:\tmp\so02.txt
  }
}
```

Content of `C:\tmp\so02.txt`:

```
Example=4
Date=07/08/2018 19:51:16
MatCaissierePDAAssoc=
NomImpPDAAssoc=
TpeForceLectPan=0
Example=1
Date=01/01/1999
```

Comment: Thank you this is perfect to solve my problem to delete single lines. Thank you!